# Right way to handle a list of multiple nearly identical classes

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have objects of 3 different classes to be handled by a single bean. These objects correspond to 3 different tables in the DB. All 3 child classes share most of their fields and have one property unique to each of them. The bean is to retrieve and display a table of all existing entries of all 3 classes. I created a parent class because I thought that it would help simplify the part where the bean handles a table of all entries in the view

```
//The parent class doesn't actually exist in the DB
public class Report{
       //fields shared by all 3 subclasses
       //Do I put @Column here?
       private long id;
       protected String sharedField1, sharedField2, sharedField3;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="report_type_a")
public class ReportA extends Report{
    //only this field is unique to this particular child class
    private String reportAField;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="report_type_b")
public class ReportB extends Report{
    //only this field is unique to this particular child class
    private String reportBField;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="report_type_c")
public class ReportC extends Report{
    //only this field is unique to this particular child class
    private String reportCField;
}

public class ReportBean{
    //a list containing objects of all 3 types to be displayed to the user later
    private ArrayList<Report> reportList;
}
```

Do Spring annotations go in the parent or the child? More importantly, is this a good way to handle this problem? Would it make more sense to dispense with a parent class?

Answer (score 0):

You just need this, everything in the super class will not be part of it's own table.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Report{
       //shared fields
       private long id;
       //Do I put @Column here?
       protected String sharedField1, sharedField2, sharedField3;
}
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html